# What is the difference between an input and observed data in a Bayesian neural network?

Tags: notation, bayesian-networks, bayesian-deep-learning, bayesian-neural-networks

I'm new to the Bayesian perspective and would appreciate clarity on this.

In a few resources concerning Bayesian deep learning (such as [this one](https://uvadlc-notebooks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_notebooks/DL2/Bayesian_Neural_Networks/dl2_bnn_tut1_students_with_answers.html)), I see this notation:

$p(y|x, D) = \int p(y|x, \theta)p(\theta|D)d\theta$

for input input $x$, corresponding output $y$, network weights and biases $\theta$, likelihood function $p(y|x, \theta)$, and "posterior distribution over the weights and biases given the observed data $D$" $p(\theta|D)$.

I would have thought that the observed data would be the input, but apparently $x$ and $D$ are not the same thing. My question is what is $D$ in this context, and how is it different than $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close:

- $x,y$ correspond to a single data point
- $\mathcal{D}$ is the whole dataset

Given this, you can read the posterior $p(y|x,D)$ as *" what's the distribution of $y$ given that I observe $x$ and my dataset is $D$"*

At this point, they say that reasoning over a whole dataset is not feasible, so they introduce a new random variable $\theta$, from which you can reason over how to solve this

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Seo you’re welcome